# What's an appropriate way to aggregate questions and answers

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of questions asked that are all very similar.  It's just that the varying use cases are different enough that the OP's don't draw the parallels and find how to apply the solutions provided.  But the titles of the questions are all so similar.

I'd like to aggregate a lot of such questions and classify them and present it as another question that acts as a guide post to the many good answers that exist.

However, I struggle to see how to ask such a question that seems on-topic or is not a duplicate.  I think this would be a valuable exercise but I haven't seen any examples on how to handle it appropriately.

What is the appropriate way to accomplish this?

Comment: Thank you for that reference.  That's what I needed.